# Should dry-stack stone post bases in a foundation be replaced?

Tags: foundation, structural, load-bearing

My daughter is looking at buying a house. Stack stones support the center beam. The home inspector says this is normal for an older house. Should she request it is repaired?

[image]

Comment: She can request it be repaired. The sellers can also say no.  The pic looks like a beam is running wild and isn't doing much of anything, but a new block is in place.  What does the inspector recommend?

Comment: Think this will come down to if it is not broken, don't fix it.  If the stones are solid and not sinking, repair would only be a time waster/make work project.  Would place it at the bottom of the list if there are other problems with the house.

Comment: While that beam in the background isn't resting on the foundation wall, it's definitely baring the weight of the large timber above it and transferring that to the ground below. Remember that while this may not meet modern building code for something being constructed today, 1000s of houses around the country (and around the world) have been built like this for centuries and are still standing the test of time.

Comment: it's possible that the beam is only there to avoid/fix sag in the floor joists and it *is* the repair, you'd need a better look to find out for sure.

Comment: I would be more concerned about the 8X8X16 hollow block on its end supporting something. Hollow block are not structured to support weight on its end like that. Laying flat on a solid base with the hole pointing up are the way they are made to sit.

Comment: The question, as it's written, is a matter of opinion. That makes it off topic here. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to ask something more specific and objective.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal and unconcerning. Probably been holding the house up for 200 odd years, will manage 200 more without need for alleged "repairs."

Dry-stack stones are a perfectly valid foundation from a time when getting concrete or even mortar was difficult and expensive.